# Create new Dataframe that is filled with simple computation from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to create a new DataFrame the rows/cells are filled in with a simple computation based on another DataFrame. Example below:

Original DF:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
 5      3      4       2     10
 3      2      1       4      2 
 2      9      7       0      4
```

Create new DF where the values in Col1-5 are being subtracted from Col5, thus desired DF being:

Desired DF

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
 5      7      6       8      0
-1      0      1      -2      0 
 2     -5     -3       4      0
```

Obviously just to get the answers, in my original value I could just create new columns where I subtract the two, but I have A LOT OF rows and thus would double the size of my DataFrame - so I'm looking to create a new one if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `sub` with `axis`

```
out = df.sub(df['Col5'], axis=0)
Out[277]: 
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0    -5    -7    -6    -8     0
1     1     0    -1     2     0
2    -2     5     3    -4     0
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow your logic verbatim, you can use broadcasting to subtract Cols 1-5 from Col5 and re-create the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(df['Col5'].to_numpy()[:, None] - df.to_numpy(),
             index=df.index,
             columns=df.columns)

   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0     5     7     6     8     0
1    -1     0     1    -2     0
2     2    -5    -3     4     0
```